# Не отображается статьи из БД в Django

Tags: django

Здравствуйте,
я добавляю статьи через админ панель но не отображается на сайте.
Прошу помочь.

Вот мои файлы

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)#Максимальная длина строки 120
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py** в папке где находиться models

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from landing.models import Articles # Импорт база данных

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('' ,
    ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:20], 
    template_name='landing/home.html')),
]
```

**views.py** в папке где находиться models

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from landing.models import Articles # Импорт база данных

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'landing/home.html')
```

Главный **url.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('landing.urls'))
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Хочу отображать таким образом html файл

```
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib import admin
from landing.models import Articles

{% extends "landing/header.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}


{% load static %}

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="tilt">
    <h2 class="text-zagalovok">{{articles.title}}</h2>
    <h6 class="text-data">Опубликовано: {{articles.date|date:"Y-m-d в H:i:s"}}</h6>
    <div class="imgadmin"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{articles.image.url}}"></div>
    <p class="text-info">{{articles.post|safe|linebreaks}}</p>
  </div>
</div>



{% include "landing/footer.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Но нет результата прошу помочь сложно понимать это тем более это 
версия уже 2.0.1

Comment: Что python-импорты делают в шаблоне?

Comment: Но если их удалять будут отображаться ?

Comment: У Вас не правильный шаблон - это как минимум.  Нужно перебирать объекты статей  циклом for

Comment: а может это связано с views? я пробовал добавить for но отображаеться только слово  "Опубликовано"

Answer (score 0):

Вы не передаете аргумент с данными в шаблон. Судя по тому что у вас в as_view() , нужно передать не articles, а queryset.

Лучше изменить струтуру сразу

1. убрать питоновские импорты из шаблонов
2. **views.py**

```
class IndexPageView(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = os.path.join('landing','home.html')
    context_object_name = 'articles'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Articles.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:20]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: any) -> dict[str, any]:
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'home page'
        return context
```

Таким образом, внутри шаблона станет доступна переменная articles, содержащая queryset, который нужно перебрать через цикл {%for article in articles%}

3. **urls.py**

```
    path('', IndexPageView.as_view(), name='home'),
```